# change HttpPost by httpurlconnection

Tags: android, httpclient, httpurlconnection

i have a method that i send some data to server and got a cookie response.this is my method:

```
 public Cookie getCookie(String username, String password) {

    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        key = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        userEncrypt = .....
        passwordEncrypt = ......
        obj.put("username", userEncrypt);
        obj.put("password", passwordEncrypt);
        obj.put("customCredential", key + ",Mobile" + deviceId);
        obj.put("isPersistent", false);

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(AppUtil.getConfig(baseActivity, App.SERVICE_AUTH) + "Login");
        request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        request.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString(), "utf-8"));
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
        if (result.toLowerCase(Locale.US).equals("true")) {

            for (Cookie cookie : client.getCookieStore().getCookies()) {
                if (cookie.getName().contains(".ASPXAUTH"))
                    return cookie;
            }
        }
```

I want to use of httpurlconnection but i do not know how could i change it ?how can i return cookie by httpurlconnection ?

this is my new method that i write:

```
           String result = "";
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(AppUtil.getConfig(this, App.SERVICE_AUTH) + "Login").openConnection();

        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        os.write((obj.toString()).getBytes("UTF-8"));
        os.flush();

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

i got 400 on responseCode . can someone help?thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, hope it works.

```
 BufferedWriter  writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

 String s = "yourJsonName =" json.toString();
 writer.write(s);
 writer.flush();
 writer.close();
```

and for getting cookie and sending it again with the next request you can do this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs",
                        Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                if (!preferences.getString("cookieName", "no_cookie").equals("no_cookie")) {
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", preferences.getString("cookieName", "no_cookie"));
                }

                for (int i = 1; (headerName = connection.getHeaderFieldKey(i)) != null; i++) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    if (headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {
                        String cookie = connection.getHeaderField(i);
                        cookie = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf(";"));
                        editor.putString("cookieName", cookie);
                        editor.apply();
                        break;
                    }
                    editor.putString("cookieName", "no_cookie");
                }

                connection.connect();
```

For getting json out of inputStream i strongly suggest you to use Gson like below:

```
private ArrayList<YourClassOfObject> readJson(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<YourClassOfObject> c = new ArrayList<>();
    try{

        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is , "UTF-8");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        YourClassOfObject[] p;
        p = gson.fromJson(reader, YourClassOfObject[].class);
        c.addAll(Arrays.asList(p));

    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ExceptionInInitializerError e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: dear milad what is this: yourJsonName ?my json does not name!!

Comment: Choose a random name so on server side you can get it with the key, it is just like key and value.

Comment: I do not have access to server. this server work with above code and i want to change client side code because this code deprecated.

Comment: I pass away on step but when I got response from server , I received  True :-(. I have to received json from server. this is my inputStream : http://codepad.org/0Aqr0cqJ

Comment: instead **client.getCookieStore().getCookies()** what i have to use on **HttpURLConnection** ?

Comment: You have to iterate through the headers and once you hit "Set-Cookie" you can fetch the session from it and then save it  to SharedPrefrences.This is written in my 2nd block of code.

Comment: in 2nd blocked code, you had written "headerName ". what is hederName and how can i find it ?

Comment: @sayreskabir It is  a String. String headerName = " " ;

Comment: dude in connection on debugin mode i found ".ASPXAUTH" on responseHeader and namesAndValues but your code can not find it and is broken from if cluse..

Comment: plz send you email that I'll send whole header response to you.I'm living tehran.

Comment: miladmoosavi77@gmail , interesting I live in karaj!

Answer (score 0):

Use Retrofit.

You’ll use annotations to describe HTTP requests, URL parameter replacement and query parameter support is integrated by default. Additionally, it provides functionality for custom headers, multipart request body, file uploads and downloads, mocking responses and much more. In later tutorials we’ll look at all of these in more detail.

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client